# How to set position of control with respect to another in Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I have 7 web browsers, in a single form, to display separate HTML formatted text (question and options). The size of text for each web-browser is variable. I wanted to display the complete text visible in web-browser, instead of using web-browser's scroll property. To achieve this I am using following code.

```
Dim Q_Rect As Rectangle = Me.wbQuestion.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle
Dim Q_BodySize As New Size(Q_Rect.Width, Q_Rect.Height)

Dim O1_Rect As Rectangle = Me.wbOption01.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle
Dim O1_BodySize As New Size(O1_Rect.Width, O1_Rect.Height)

Me.wbQuestion.Size = Q_BodySize
Me.wbOption01.Size = O1_BodySize
```

and so on..

But, **if I use the above mentioned code to dynamically resize, I am facing overlapping problem.** That is, when the text in my Question Web-browser is huge, it overlaps with the text of Options Web-browser (and similarly with other options).

Only solution to this, I can think of is to **allocate position of web-browser and other controls relative to each other, instead of using absolute x, y position**.

But I dont know how to do that.
Please help me with this, or let me know if there is any other way to achieve this?

(I am using visual basic of visual studio 2013)

Thanks.

Comment: Put all  your browsers inside a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the X and Y location of the wbQuestion web browser.
Then place the wbOption01 web browser according to that location.

If you want to place it under it then Location X will be the same.
Then you need to take the Y location and add the wbQuestion web browser Height to it + the space you want it to have under the web browser.

And if you want to place it next to it you need to change the X "Add the Width + the space you want it to have next to the web browser"

Place the code under the code where you resize the web browser.

So to place it under the web browser you use.

```
Me.wbOption01.Location = New Point(Me.wbQuestion.Location.X, Me.wbQuestion.Location.Y + Me.wbQuestion.Height + 10)
```

And to place it next to the web browser you use.

```
Me.wbOption01.Location = New Point(Me.wbQuestion.Location.X + Me.wbQuestion.Width + 10, Me.wbQuestion.Location.Y)
```

Comment: although i have moved to FlowLayoutPanel, but your answer seems to be good enough to marked as Accepted ans. Thanks.